# ASP.Net Forms authentication provider issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2008, forms-authentication

I am using VSTS 2008 + .Net 3.5 + ASP.Net to develop a simple web application. And I am using Forms authentication for my web site (I use command aspnet_regsql.exe to create a new database in SQL Server 2008 Enterprise to host database for Forms Authentication. I am not using SQL Server Express.).

I am learning Forms authentication from here,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx#paght000022_usingthesqlmembershipprovider

my question is for the name of membership defaultProvider, the value must be "SqlProvider"? Or I can use any arbitrary name, for example like this (I replace the value "SqlProvider" to "MyTestSqlProvider")?

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="MySqlConnection" connectionString="Data Source=MySqlServer;Initial Catalog=aspnetdb;Integrated Security=SSPI;" />
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
...
  <membership defaultProvider="MyTestSqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add 
        name="MyTestSqlProvider" 
        type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" 
        connectionStringName="MySqlConnection"
        applicationName="MyApplication"
        enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
        enablePasswordReset="true"
        requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
        requiresUniqueEmail="true"
        passwordFormat="Hashed" />
    </providers>
  </membership>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have there is perfectly find. The name is just there so you can refer to *that particular* provider. So as long as the name is unqiue, then it doesn't really matter what it is (you could call it "BlahBlahGoobledegook" and it wouldn't matter.

Comment: So, I can use my special provider name "MyTestSqlProvider" along with the specific type name "System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"? Means, no matter what provider names I am using, I can use "System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" as type?